# Strange caps-lock behavior on Ubuntu laptops

Tags: keyboard, debugging

So two weeks ago I got a new laptop and put Ubuntu on it to replace Windows 10 it came with. I was previously a MacOS user, and have also run Windows in the past. I am on my second laptop running Ubuntu in these two weeks (returned the first one because the build quality was sub-par) and things are mostly great. However, both laptops had some strange caps-lock behavior, which makes me think it isn't a hardware / driver issue but a software difference from MacOS. Basically when I type on these laptops, the caps-lock constantly persists for an extra letter even though I turn it off. So the text WOuld LOok LIke THis. Almost like caps-lock has a slight delay in turning off. Is this delay something I can change in the software somewhere or is this a bug? The laptop is a 15 HP Envy x360 with AMD Ryzen 5 4500U.

Comment: This would be difficult to answer without knowing what computer you're actually using. Can you update your question to include the brand and model? This will make it much easier for someone to offer a possible solution, if one exists 

Comment: Updated, it is an HP Envy X360 with AMD Ryzen 5 CPU

Comment: Are you turning on caps lock for a single letter, as in the example you give? Why not just use shift?

Comment: I have always used caps lock for single letter, do most people use shift? Maybe this is the solution then.